# What makes PHP's mail() function so slow?

Tags: php, email, networking, gmail

I made a quick PHP script on my server containing a call to mail() and started testing it. The html page always loads instantly, so I assume that means the PHP containing the call to mail() is finished executing. However, the emails sent from mail() are only ever being received every 10-20 minutes after the call. Why the delay? Does mail() trigger external programs? (the emails are being sent to a gmail email account if that's relevant)

Comment: That has nothing to do with `mail()`.  It is the SMTP mail delivery (which PHP hands off the message to) which is taking time. Possibly, the delay you see is greylisting on the receiving server, meaning that the receiving mail server refuses to accept the message until the sending server (which your PHP script handed it to) tries a few times.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Should have been an answer IMO.

Comment: @thejh I'll convert it.

Comment: Is there any way I can speed up the process for near-instant placement of the email in the recipient's inbox ?

Comment: @user2593666 No, it's totally out of your hands. It depends on the actions of at least two, but often more than two servers which are not under your control, and certainly not under PHP's control.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i have this same problem running on my local server. I suppose gmail is more likely to accept my request when i move to a proper server on the www with a proper domain name, right?

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi Yes, that's very likely. If the receiving server has received enough messages from a sender and they're known to be good and not spammy, it may dial back the greylisting and start accepting more readily.

Comment: You could also try and talk to spamhaus and your ISP, they tend to do a majority of the grey-listing and email sending limits.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing has nothing to do with PHP's  `mail()` function. Instead, it is the SMTP mail server which PHP hands off the message to, which is taking time to deliver.  That service is known as [a mail transport agent, or MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_transport_agent).

There are lots of potential reasons it won't be delivered immediately. Possibly, the delay you see is [greylisting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting) on the receiving server, meaning that the receiving mail server refuses to accept the message until the sending server (which your PHP script handed it to) tries a few times to resend it.  Well-behaved MTA's will retry failed send attempts, but spam servers often don't, making this a simple but effective method for cutting down spam.

It could even be as simple as a long queue of messages on the SMTP server waiting to be sent, whereby yours are waiting in line.  (Really greylisting is more probable though)

Most important to remember though is that email is *not* intended to be instantaneous and therefore never guaranteed to be instantaneous. In the past decade or so we've gotten accustomed by and large to email being delivered really quickly, but you can never promise quick delivery.

Comment: Thanks, helped me if not the OP

Answer (score 10):

Just as @Michael Berkowski said, it's not the mail() function itself. mail() works by calling your systems built in SMTP courier software. It then automatically negotiates the conversation with the receiving system by performing the necessary DNS lookups to find the proper mail server. Then that server picks up your message, checks your system through grey-listing and reverse DNS lookups, scans it and runs it against it's own spam/virus protection, then finally delivers. Also many mail servers delay unknown sending servers to prevent against mail DOS'ing and fishers.

Comment: In comparison to the answer of @MichaelBerkowski, this has some new information. Much appreciated, thank you !

Comment: I was writing my answer at the same time as him. lol. His was just a comment and I thought I'd fill in some background since I've coded a mail server.

Answer (score 2):

Today I was setting up my local devserver and had same problem. Sending mail fom php via mail()-function was very slow. As already mentioned, the problem was the sendmail-setup (/var/log/mail.log):

```
My unqualified host name (devserver) unknown; sleeping for retry
```

I had to make my hostname resolvable folling this guide:
https://linuxconfig.org/sendmail-unqualified-hostname-unknown-sleeping-for-retry-unqualified-hostname

tldr;
edit /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost devserver
127.0.1.1       devserver
```

Maybe it will help somebody, too

Comment: Thank you very much for this PERFECT Answer. Had the same issue and now I know a bit more about it and was able to solve it. Very good Link!