# Why phpmailer->send() return true but I don't get the email?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Here is my function:

```
function send_mail($email_from, $password, $email_to, $subject, $body, $name_from = "Lamtakam"){
    $phpMailer = new PHPMailer(true);
    // $phpMailer->SMTPDebug = true;
    $phpMailer->isSMTP();
    $phpMailer->Host = "smtp.zoho.com";
    $phpMailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $phpMailer->Username = $email_from;
    $phpMailer->Password = $password;
    $phpMailer->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $phpMailer->Port = 587;
    $phpMailer->isHTML(true);
    $phpMailer->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $phpMailer->setFrom($email_from, $name_from);
    $phpMailer->addAddress($email_to);
    $phpMailer->Subject = $subject;
    $phpMailer->Body = $body;
    return $phpMailer->send();
}
```

When I use it locally (xampp) it works well. But recently I've uploaded my website on the server (linux ubuntu) and sadly emails don't be sent. Actually `$phpMailer->send()` returns true, but I don't get the email neither in the inbox nor spam. Why and how can I fix it?

---

Ok, after about 30min I get the email in the inbox. Now my question is what's the reason of this huge delay?

Comment: "Now my question is what's the reason of this huge delay?" Your mail service.

Comment: @fyroc I use zoho mail service .. I don't use my own server mail service.

Comment: Sorry.. the huge delay is either the outgoing or incoming mail server being slow to process the email

Comment: SMTP is a store-and-forward protocol that does not make any delivery guarantees. Receiving servers often limit delivery speed (via greylisting, greetdelay, deferral, throttling, tarpitting etc) in order to control spam and local resource consumption. Want to know what's happening? Look at your mail server logs.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325269/what-makes-phps-mail-function-so-slow) is quite relevant. In short, it is not PHP, but SMTP, the thing that the PHP script passes the mail to for delivery, that is causing the delay. SMTP has some weird behavior that can cause this, the most common being [greylisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting). Greylisting attempts to reduce spam and prevent unverified emails by waiting for the request to be made multiple times before processing it.

If you want to send mail more quickly, I recommend using an API such as [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/) which has its own SMTP servers. API's tend to be a lot more reliable, fast, and much easier to work with. In general, the PHP `mail()` function is slow, and there's no way around that.

Comment: Indeed it is most likely to be something like greylisting in this case, but it's not true that `mail()` is inherently slow (though it's slower and less safe than SMTP to localhost), nor that remote HTTP APIs are going to be faster. I have no trouble sending > 700k messages/hour using SMTP to nearby mail servers.

Comment: As far as I've heard, it depends heavily on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code which tries to catch any phpmailer exceptions.

```
function send_mail($email_from, $password, $email_to, $subject, $body, $name_from = "Lamtakam"){

    $phpMailer = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {

        $phpMailer->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $phpMailer->isSMTP();
        $phpMailer->Host = "smtp.zoho.com";
        $phpMailer->SMTPAuth = true;
        $phpMailer->Username = $email_from;
        $phpMailer->Password = $password;
        $phpMailer->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $phpMailer->Port = 587;
        $phpMailer->isHTML(true);
        $phpMailer->CharSet = "UTF-8";
        $phpMailer->setFrom($email_from, $name_from);
        $phpMailer->addAddress($email_to);
        $phpMailer->Subject = $subject;
        $phpMailer->Body = $body;
        $phpMailer->send();

    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {

        die($e->errorMessage());

    }

}
```

If it doesn't work check with your host if port 587 is open

Comment: I see that you have updated your question since I posted this answer. Do not use my answer in production. It was only meant to help you to debug the error.

Comment: Alright, just take the die off and perhaps return something... best of luck

Comment: Don't post code without explaining specifically *why* it solves the question asked. "It works for me" isn't a valid reason.